# R: create data frame with the edges of each node liking the same object

Tags: r, dataframe, nodes, social-networking, edges

I am creating a network where people are connected by what they like. I have a dataframe containing what people like and I want to obtain a dataframe where each person is paired with those how liked the same object

what I have

input:

```
object   person
 1        1
 1        2 
 1        3
 2        2
 2        3
 3        3
 4        1
 4        4
```

what I want to obtain

result:

```
person1 person2   object
1       2         1
1       3         1
2       3         1
2       3         2
1       4         4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a data.table solution

**sample data**

```
library( data.table )
DT <- fread("object   person
1        1
1        2 
1        3
2        2
2        3
3        3
4        1
4        4")
```

**code**

```
DT[, { #suppress immediate output by using {}
       if( length(person) > 1) {     #combinations only possible for >1 persons
         temp <-  combn( person, 2)  #get all possible 2-person combinations
         list( person1 = temp[1,],   #add combinations to named list
               person2 = temp[2,] )  
         } #end if
     }, #now present the finalt output (i.e. the named list) , 
   by = object ] #for each object
```

**output**

```
#    object person1 person2
# 1:      1       1       2
# 2:      1       1       3
# 3:      1       2       3
# 4:      2       2       3
# 5:      4       1       4
```

Comment: it gives me this error: Error: unexpected symbol in:
"     } #now present the finalt output (i.e. the named list) , 
   by"

Comment: no, it s a data.frame, but I tried your code comping and pasting your example and it gives me this error

Comment: now I was trying with group_by: dat <- dat %>% group_by(object , person) %>%
    summarize(n = person) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(object) %>%
    summarize(Series = paste(n, collapse = ','))
with this I was able to identify each people liking the same object and put them in a string separated by a comma, but I still need to create each combinations of persons liking the same object and put each combination in a row

Comment: the above solution on `data.table`-format data. see sample data provided.  Make your data.frame a data.table by using: `data.table::setDT( yourdataframe )`.

Comment: haha.. the code was missing a comma... see updated code in answer above, now with a comma added after the laste `}`.. sorry for the confusion..